# python package installed by setuptools can't be uninstalled successfully

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, uninstallation

I install a python package with the `setuptools`:

```
python setup.py develop --user
```

To uninstall the package, I have tried the following methods:

1.

```
python setup.py develop --uninstall
```

2.

```
python setup.py develop --uninstall --user
```

3.

```
python setup.py install --record files.txt
xargs rm -rf < files.txt
```

However, these don't work.

I can still `import MyPackage` successfully under every conda envs.

Comment: Run `python -c "import MyPackage; print(MyPackage.__file__)"` and check where the file is located. It's probably imported from your local source code checkout.

Answer (score 1):

The uninstall command is determined depending on the install command.

1.

```
# install
python setup.py install
```

```
# uninstall
python setup.py install --record files.txt
xargs rm -rf < files.txt
```

2.

```
# install
python setup.py develop
```

```
# uninstall 
python setup.py develop --uninstall
```

3.

```
# install
python setup.py develop --user
```

```
# uninstall 
python setup.py develop --uninstall --user
```